# Question on Parseval's theorem

Tags: fourier-analysis

If $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}|a_k|^2$ is not finite, does Parseval's theorem say that the Fourier transform of $a_k$ is also not finite?

Comment: I think in this case the Fourier transform is not even defined.

Comment: The Fourier transform is defined, at least in the sense of tempered distributions, as long as $|a_k|$ is bounded by a polynomial.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks Robert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it says is there is no square-integrable function on $[0,2\pi]$ whose inverse Fourier transform is $a_k$.